# Standars for assigning maturities and hedging account balances in commercial banks

Tags: banks

I was wondering wich is the standard for pricing clients account balances in commercial banks. Is there any book that adress alm problems?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the p.65 of this [document](https://www.unicreditbank.ru/content/dam/cee2020-pws-ru/issuer-reports/finance/msfo/2015/UCB%20IFRS%20Cons%20FS%2015-e.pdf). They reveal some information regarding the mapping of the assets and liabilities. Based on this mapping, you could perform gap analysis and see if you have any deficit in a given maturity slot and then hedge accordingly.

Joel Bessis' books on Banking Risk Management may also be useful.

**UPDATE:** Alright, here is the approach that is used:

$V(T) = V_0 e^{(-q \sigma \sqrt{T - 0.5 T \sigma^2})}$

$V_0$ - clients' account balances today (or on calculation date)

$T$ - periods of mapping (could be 3M, 6M, 9M, 1Y, etc.)

$q$ - quantile (95%, 99%, etc.)

$\sigma$ - volatility of the clients' account balances over a time period (12M, 24M, 36M)

Basically, the account balance follows GBM with chosen confidence level $q$.

Comment: The document only says that they used a statisticcal aproach, but not how it was done.

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.